# "Debussy, but EPIC for the new Godzilla trailer"

Tags: headline-english

I have read (by accident, I'm sorry) a short news article that had the following headline:

> Debussy, but EPIC for the new Godzilla trailer

The article text for this was as followed:

> Godzilla 2: King of the Monsters continues the trend of making
>   classical music EPIC by turning Claude Debussy's "Clair de Lune" into
>   a spine-tingling blast of EPICness.

Is this a "correct" or widely understood way to form a headline in english? What kind of construct is this? A noun followed by ", but [adverb] ..."? What is this supposed to express?

Comment: Try mentally adding the words “it is” before *Debussy* and *epic* in the headline. That’s what it is expressing.

Comment: but why "but"? :)

Comment: I suppose they didn’t consider Debussy particularly epic in its normal context.

Comment: so it is "Debussy is not really epic, but it is epic for the new Godzilla trailer." ?

Comment: *But* draws contrast. Maybe the person thought one was music that makes people relax, while the other was a show that makes people go, “Wow!”

Comment: Wait... are you concerned about the grammar (dropping normally required words) or about the aesthetics of applying the adjective 'epic' to certain kinds of music?

Comment: It's fine grammatically but yeah it's utterly horrible in all the other ways. I have no idea why anyone would write like that, and more to the point, I have no idea why you'd read such trash.

Comment: And I can't find it on knowyourmeme, but the actual answer to your question is, "X but it's Y" is a meme. That is all. YouTube is full of it to the brim right now. But it's going out of style already.

Comment: @Mitch I am concerned about the grammatical correctness, is correct to drop words like this in a headline or at least a very commonly used style in English speaking journalism. If this is correct can you cite or explain the rules?

Comment: Read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese

Comment: @JohnFeltz Actually I am more or less aware of everything described in that Wikipedia article but the above headline can’t really be explained with that wiki article. A noun/name standing alone followed by a comma, I haven‘t seen this before.

Comment: Headlines have conflicting interests: Taking up limited space while drawing the reader into reading the article that follows. To that end, quick & sexy often tops graceful.